# Create an orphan branch without using the orphan flag

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I have an existing repo with some branches. I want to create a new branch without any history on that repo. I'm trying to do this using Dulwich, which supports most git operations, though not the orphan flag.

What are the equivalent Git operations to create an orphan branch without actually using that flag? Ideally i'd like to:

- clone the repo
- make a new branch with the contents of the repo, but without history
- push the branch to the repo

Is this possible or do I need to create a new branch that's empty, clone to a separate directory and copy the contents back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I don't use Dulwich and cannot say for sure anything about it.  Depending on how much of Git it re-implements from scratch, what *Git* does may be irrelevant.

An orphan branch, in Git, is actually a branch that doesn't exist.  What `git checkout --orphan newbranch` does is to write the name `newbranch` into `HEAD`, without actually creating `newbranch`.

More specifically, aside from consistency and error checking,<sup>1</sup> the difference between:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

and:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

is that the former runs:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/newbranch HEAD && \
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch
```

and the latter runs:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch
```

The first step, `git update-ref`, actually creates the branch.

The second step, `git symbolic-ref`, sets us up to be "on" the branch.

An orphan branch, then, is one that we are "on" that does not exist.

The actual branch *creation* happens later, when we make a new commit.  So it's not `git checkout` that creates these; it's `git commit`!  The commit operation fundamentally consists of:

1. turn the current index into a tree object (`git write-tree`);
2. find the parent ID(s) for the current commit (read `HEAD` and check for pending merges);
3. collect the remaining metadata (author, committer, email addresses ,time stamps, log message);
4. create a commit object that has the information from the earlier steps;
5. write the new commit object's hash ID through `HEAD` into the current branch name (or directly into `HEAD` if `HEAD` is detached).

Step 5 is where the branch gets created.  During step 2, if `HEAD` names a branch that does not exist, it contributes no parent hash ID, so that the new commit has no parents (presumably there are no recorded additional parents for merges at this time).

*If* Dulwich behaves the same as Git here—it very well might, because this peculiar state, of being on a branch that does not exist, is how Git bootstraps an *empty* repository, and it's the obvious way to do it—then all you have to do to implement what you want directly is to rewrite the `HEAD` information (however Dulwich stores it) so that it points to this non-existent branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git checkout -b newbranch` also offers `git checkout -b newbranch startpoint`.  Using a different starting point has a whole cascade of side effects: Git first attempts to do `git checkout startpoint` internally, which may make arbitrary modifications to index and work-tree.

Comment: You seem to be absolutely correct! I updated the symbolic-ref to a non-existent branch and it seemed to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks!